# Se pueden declarar prototipos de clases en c++

Tags: c++

```
class A {
  B x;
};

class B {
 A x;
};
```

El compilador me dice que `B` no es un tipo.

Answer (score 4):

Se puede. Pero lo que intentas hacer es claramente incorrecto, y no hay forma de *predeclarar* las clases para que tu código funcione.

El compilador **ha de conocer el tamaño** de todos los tipos usados. Y ya vemos tu problema: La `class A` *contiene* una instancia de la `class B`, que *contiene* una instancia de `class A`, que *contiene* una instancia de la `class B`, que contiene ...

Para que tu código funcione, has de cambiar la definición de, al menos, una de las clases. De forma que, en lugar de usar una instancia completa de la otra, use un *puntero*:

```
class B;

class A {
  B *b;
};

class B {
  A a;
};
```

Ya has visto como se *predeclara* una clase: `class B;`. **Pero** al predeclararla, solo podemos trabajar con *punteros* y *referencias* a ella: como dijimos antes, el compilador **necesita conocer el tamaño**. Al predeclararla, no estamos informando del tamaño real de la clase ... pero el tamaño de **un puntero a nuestra clase** es conocido en todo momento.

Answer (score 3):

Poco hay que añadir a la respuesta de [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/210118/2742), ha explicado perfectamente que no puedes definir un objeto en C++ sin conocer el tamaño del mismo. Quisiera añadir una posible solución al problema que planteas:

#### Pointer to implementation ([pImpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)).

La implementación en puntero (conocida como [pImpl [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) en Inglés) es un patrón de diseño que separa los detalles de implementación de un objeto de su representación al situarlos en un objeto separado al que se accede mediante un puntero:

```
class pImplA;
class pImplB;

class A
{
    pImplA *pA{nullptr};
public:
    A();
    ~A() { delete pA; }
};

class B
{
    pImplB *pB{nullptr};
public:
    B();
    ~B() { delete pB; }
};
```

Los punteros `pImplA` y `pImplB` son los que apuntan a la implementación real, que se deberá definir más adelante:

```
class pImplA
{
    B x;
};

class pImplB
{
    A x;
};
```

Para finalizar, hay que definir (en un archivo de código, no de cabecera) los constructores de `A` y `B`:

```
A::A() : pA{new pImplA}{}
B::B() : pB{new pImplB}{}
```

Ve con cuidado, tal y como está definido el código, se creará un bucle recursivo de `A` creando `B` creando `A` creando `B` creando `A`... pero entiendo que en una implementación real no se dará el caso pues tu código era sólo ilustrativo ¿no?.